# matlab linprog inequality constraint is a matrix - how to convert to a vector

Tags: matlab, concatenation, linear-programming

I have the following code:

```
test = horzcat(-PV_test, -WT_output);
f = [((CRF * CC_PV) / PVenergy) + OM_PV; ((CRF * CC_WT) / WTenergy) + OM_WT];
A = test;
b = -Demand;
lb = zeros(2,1);
ub = [max_PV_area max_WT_area];
x = linprog(f, A, b, [], [], lb, ub)
```

Where:

```
b = 365 x 24
PV_test = 365x24
WT_output  = 365 x 24
test = 365 x 48 (from matrix concatenation)
```

It seems that `Demand` is a matrix when it should be a vector. How do I convert this to a vector and keep the same elements in the same "place"?

Also, is the matrix concatenation the best way to do this? I am trying to find an optimum `x1` and `x2` value for the entire data set.

Comment: What is the size of the matrix `Demand`?

Comment: However, the size of `A` is 365x48. Your dimensions are mismatching. If we use only the values from one column from `b`, or all the values, it wouldn't match the dimensions of `A`. Please clarify that.

Comment: I see the mismatch but can't figure a way to construct a matrix for one element per hour of the year to match. Do you have any suggestions on reshaping?

Comment: It's not about reshaping. You need `b` to have the same number of elements as every column in `A`.